# How to solve PyLint error: Invalid Syntax when my syntax is all correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am making a python function that gets a parameter of a character and then prints if the character is a uppercase, lowercase, a number or a special character. I get this error from Pylint

> invalid syntax (, line 529)pylint(syntax-error)

```
#Finding if a number is a lowercase, uppercase, number or a special character
def check(charcater):
    character_ascii = ord(character)
    if character_ascii >= 97 and <= 122:
        print('The character',character,'is a lowercase letter')
    elif character_ascii >= 65 and <= 90:
        print('The character',character,'is a uppercase letter')
    elif character_ascii >= 48 and <= 57:
        print('The character',character,'is a number')
    else :
        print('The character',character,'is a special character')
```

I get the error here

```
if character_ascii >= 97 and <= 122:
                              ^
```

Please help me solve this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think your syntax is correct? It isn't. `and` doesn't distribute over the comparison operators; each one needs two operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate comparison expressions, joined by `and`, and each one requires two operands.

```
if character_ascii >= 97 and character_ascii <= 122:
```

However, comparison operators allow for *chaining*, which allows you to include multiple comparisons in a *single* expression. The above is equivalent to

```
if 97 <= character_ascii <= 122:
```

In general, `x op1 y op2 z` is equivalent to `x op1 y and y op2 z` for any two comparison operators `op1` and `op2`. Comparison operators are

- `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`
- `==`, `!=`
- `is`, `is not`
- `in` `not in`

Answer (score 0):

comparison operators need a value on both sides so try changing them to this:

```py
def check(charcater):
    character_ascii = ord(character)
    if character_ascii >= 97 and character_ascii <= 122:
        print('The character',character,'is a lowercase letter')
    elif character_ascii >= 65 and character_ascii <= 90:
        print('The character',character,'is a uppercase letter')
    elif character_ascii >= 48 and character_ascii <= 57:
        print('The character',character,'is a number')
    else :
        print('The character',character,'is a special character')
```